# Storyboard corruption on file open

Tags: ios, storyboard, corruption

I am having a problem where my content is repeatedly being shifted to the right in the storyboard for multiple view controllers when I open the project. I have done nothing at this point, simply opened it. Further, undoing the modifications through git does nothing. I fix the problems and go about my day adding new features... the apps run fine in the phone and appear normal in the storyboard. However, when I open the project the next day, same thing happens and I have to fix everything again. Has anyone else experienced this issue, and what was your resolution to the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently there is just some display bug in Xcode. When I click on a new size class and click back, the elements are restored to their correct size. This was maddening, but apparently it's working fine now if I do this quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. On my first View Controller, I had some labels that had somehow become set to a width of zero. After I fixed them, and embedded them in a stack, the problem resolved itself. I have no idea how this screwed up several other view controllers; however, fingers crossed, the corruption hasn't happened again since I fixed it.

Comment: Well, apparently this didn't fix the problem. Despite everything being normal for a few days, the corruption appeared in exactly the same manner today for no apparent reason.

Comment: It just keeps happening over and over and over again. No idea. Very frustrating.